# how a function change in a loop with newtonsys command matlab

Tags: matlab

i want to change function variable at each step in a for loop in matlab.
i take these steps:
i created my mfile function

```
function [jfun,fun]=air(x,vt,ty,tz,p2,y0)

    jfun=[(cos(tz)*cos(ty)*vt/9.81)*(1-exp(-9.81*x(2)/vt)),...
          x(1)*cos(tz)*cos(ty)*exp(-9.81*x(1)/vt);
          (-vt*sin(tz)*cos(ty)/9.81)*exp(-9.81*x(1)/vt),...
          (x(1)*sin(tz)*cos(ty)*+vt)*exp(-9.81*x(1)/vt)];
    fun=[(x(1)*cos(ty)*cos(tz)*vt/9.81)*(1-exp(-9.81*x(2)/vt))-p2;...
        (vt/9.81)*(x(1)*sin(tz)*cos(ty)+vt)*(1-exp(-9.81*x(2)/vt))-vt*x(2)+y0];
end
```

and then i used newtonSys command:

```
ty=rad(-23)
tz=rad(15)
p2=1.8
vt=8.4925
y0=0.2
myfun=@(x)air(x,vt,ty,tz,p2,y0)
x=newtonSys(myfun,[15 5],0.000001,0.000001,500,1)
```

and matlab answer:
Error in ==> Untitled18 at 7
x=newtonSys(myfun,[15 5],0.000001,0.000001,500,1)
i guess that its because of wrong use of function handle and for my function i have to use another command or i have to use another method for solving 2nonlinear equation.

Answer (score 1):

First, you haven't displayed the entire error. MATLAB should tell you what the actual error is, so unless you tell us that, we won't know what's wrong.

Secondly I don't see `newtonSys` in my system, or in the online MATLAB documentation. So most likely it is an external program, which most people here might not be familiar with. The closest I found from a quick Google search was [this](http://www.ens.utulsa.edu/~class_diaz/cs2503/Fall97/fall97/inverse/node6.html), which is an implementation of Newton's method for approximating the root of a non-linear system of n-equations. Are you using the same file? If so, if you look at the comments, it says that you need to pass the function as a string. So you'd have to pass `myfun` as `'myfun'`.

If not, could you edit your question and add the contents of the function that you're using? Without these, it's near impossible to answer your question.